# Module '"node_modules/@angular/animations/animations"' has no exported member 'AnimationBuilder'

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, build, transpiler

I just followed [these](http://blog.ionic.io/updates-for-all-ionic-angular-3-7-and-more/) instructions in an effort to get my app to get my app to load (it is hanging on the splash screen).

In short I did this:

```
npm install -g ionic@latest
npm install ionic-angular@3.7.0 --save
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@3.0.0 --save-dev
npm install @angular/core@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/common@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/compiler@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/forms@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/http@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/platform-browser@4.4.3 --save
npm install @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@4.4.3 --save
npm install rxjs@5.4.3 --save
npm install zone.js@0.8.17 --save
```

Now when I run `ionic package build ios` I get these errors:

```
[14:21:32]  typescript: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_builder.d.ts, line: 8 
            Module '"/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations"' has no exported 
            member 'AnimationBuilder'. 

       L7:      constructor(rootRenderer: RendererFactory2, doc: any);
       L8:      build(animation: AnimationMetadata | AnimationMetadata[]): AnimationFactory;

[14:21:32]  typescript: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_builder.d.ts, line: 8 
            Module '"/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations"' has no exported 
            member 'AnimationFactory'. 

       L7:      constructor(rootRenderer: RendererFactory2, doc: any);
       L8:      build(animation: AnimationMetadata | AnimationMetadata[]): AnimationFactory;

[14:21:32]  typescript: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/animation_builder.d.ts, line: 8 
            Module '"/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@angular/animations/animations"' has no exported 
            member 'AnimationOptions'. 

       L7:      constructor(rootRenderer: RendererFactory2, doc: any);
       L8:      build(animation: AnimationMetadata | AnimationMetadata[]): AnimationFactory;

[14:21:32]  typescript: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts, line: 5 
            Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'flush' from 
            class 'AnimationEngine'. 

       L4:  import { AnimationRendererFactory } from './animation_renderer';
       L5:  export declare class InjectableAnimationEngine extends AnimationEngine {
       L6:      constructor(driver: AnimationDriver, normalizer: AnimationStyleNormalizer);

[14:21:32]  typescript: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts, line: 5 
            Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'listen' from 
            class 'AnimationEngine'. 

       L4:  import { AnimationRendererFactory } from './animation_renderer';
       L5:  export declare class InjectableAnimationEngine extends AnimationEngine {
       L6:      constructor(driver: AnimationDriver, normalizer: AnimationStyleNormalizer);

[14:21:32]  typescript: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts, line: 5 
            Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'onInsert' from 
            class 'AnimationEngine'. 

       L4:  import { AnimationRendererFactory } from './animation_renderer';
       L5:  export declare class InjectableAnimationEngine extends AnimationEngine {
       L6:      constructor(driver: AnimationDriver, normalizer: AnimationStyleNormalizer);

[14:21:32]  typescript: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts, line: 5 
            Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'onRemove' from 
            class 'AnimationEngine'. 

       L4:  import { AnimationRendererFactory } from './animation_renderer';
       L5:  export declare class InjectableAnimationEngine extends AnimationEngine {
       L6:      constructor(driver: AnimationDriver, normalizer: AnimationStyleNormalizer);

[14:21:32]  typescript: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts, line: 5 
            Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 
            'registerTrigger' from class 'AnimationEngine'. 

       L4:  import { AnimationRendererFactory } from './animation_renderer';
       L5:  export declare class InjectableAnimationEngine extends AnimationEngine {
       L6:      constructor(driver: AnimationDriver, normalizer: AnimationStyleNormalizer);

[14:21:32]  typescript: node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/animations/src/providers.d.ts, line: 5 
            Non-abstract class 'InjectableAnimationEngine' does not implement inherited abstract member 'setProperty' 
            from class 'AnimationEngine'. 

       L4:  import { AnimationRendererFactory } from './animation_renderer';
       L5:  export declare class InjectableAnimationEngine extends AnimationEngine {
       L6:      constructor(driver: AnimationDriver, normalizer: AnimationStyleNormalizer);

Error: Failed to transpile program
    at new BuildError (/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
    at /Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:159:20
    at transpileWorker (/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:107:12)
    at Object.transpile (/Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/transpile.js:64:12)
    at /Users/eamonwhite/ionicmane/myApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/build.js:106:82
```

I checked the folder and I think all of the things it isn't finding are there (in the `d.ts` files).

Any help would be great. I was doing this in an effort to get my app running, after the release of `iOS 11` it started to get stuck loading on the `splashscreen`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I needed to update the animations module:

`npm install @angular/animations@latest --save`

Comment: Your answer save me, :D

Comment: Yup... I had animations 7 with core 5, this worked thank you!